# Reinforcement learning in C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

- I intend to use Reinforcement learning in my project but I do not know much how to implement it..
- So I am looking for a library with different RL algorithms that I can use in my C# project..

Thanks

Please Note:
I found NeuronDotNet library for neural networks, I am now looking for RL library..

EDIT: Or a Dot NET library

Comment: Does the library have to be written in C#, or could be be written in another .NET language? You'd still be able to use it in your C# project.

Comment: I just want to be able to use it in C#.. does not matter the language it is written with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For who care, I have found this library for socket supported languages (C#):
[Rl-Glue](http://glue.rl-community.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: Linq to the google code project : http://code.google.com/p/rl-library/

Answer (score 3):

I encourage you to try this solution:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotrl/

I am the main author, any comments are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to implement them because you lack an understanding of the algorithms, a book by Sutton and Barton should help clear up any issues you have.

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html

But otherwise, what you found should suit your needs.